# How to derive the variance of this MLE estimator

Tags: statistics, estimation, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

Let $(x_i, Y_i)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ be independent observations on $n$ subjects, such that $$Y_i|x_i\sim N(x_i\beta, \sigma^2)$$ where $(\beta, \sigma^2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$ are unknown coefficients.

I computed the maximum likelihood estimate $\hat\beta$ of $\beta$, which is $\hat\beta = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_{i}x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$, and we want to compute **the variance of this estimator** $\hat\beta$.

Using that $Var(\hat\beta)= E[\hat\beta^2]-E[\hat\beta]^2$, I would only need $E[\hat\beta^2]$ to get the variance, as I already showed $E[\hat\beta]=\beta$, but I'm struggling with it.

$$E[\hat\beta^2]=E[(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^n y_{i}x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2})^2]=\frac{1}{(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2)^2}E[(\sum_{i=1}^n y_{i}x_i)^2]$$

I do not really know how to compute this expectation. Any help would be appreaciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y_{i}|x_{i} \sim \mathcal{N}(x_{i}\beta | \sigma^2) \Leftrightarrow y_{i} = \beta x_{i} + \epsilon_{i}, \ \epsilon_{i} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$

It's easier to find $\mathbb{D}(\hat \beta)$ directly - not by finding $\mathbb{E}(\hat{\beta}^2)$.

$\mathbb{D}(\hat \beta) = \mathbb{D}\left( \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n y_{i}x_{i}}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_{i}^2}  \right) = \frac{1}{\left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_{i}^2  \right)^2} \mathbb{D}\left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_{i}\beta + \epsilon_{i})\cdot x_{i}  \right) = \frac{1}{\left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_{i}^2  \right)^2} \mathbb{D}\left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \epsilon_{i}\cdot x_{i} + \beta \cdot \underbrace{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_{i}^2 }_{\text{nonrandom}}  \right) = \frac{1}{\left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_{i}^2  \right)^2} \mathbb{D}\left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \epsilon_{i}\cdot x_{i} \right) = \frac{1}{\left( \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_{i}^2  \right)^2}  \sum\limits_{i=1}^n \mathbb{D}(\epsilon_{i})\cdot x_{i}^2 =  \frac{\sigma^2 \cdot \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_{i}^2 }{\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_{i}^2  \right)^2} = \boxed{\frac{\sigma^2}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_{i}^2}}$

Comment: Shouldn't the fraction you take out from the variance be sum of $x_i^2$, instead of sum of $x_i$?

Comment: @eseou Hope you noticed that this answer finds $\operatorname{Var}(\hat\beta\mid x)$ as opposed to $\operatorname{Var}(\hat\beta)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\epsilon_i=Y_i-x_i\beta$. Then $\epsilon_i\mid x_i\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and
$$
\operatorname{Var}(\hat{\beta})=\mathsf{E}[\hat{\beta}-\beta]^2=\mathsf{E}\left[\left(\sum x_i^2\right)^{-2}\left(\sum \epsilon_i x_i\right)^2\right].
$$
Conditionally on $X\equiv (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}[(\hat{\beta}-\beta)^2\mid X]&=\left(\sum x_i^2\right)^{-2}\sum \operatorname{Var}(\epsilon_ix_i)\\
&=\left(\sum x_i^2\right)^{-2}\sum x_i^2 \sigma^2=\sigma^2\left(\sum x_i^2\right)^{-1}.
\end{align}
Therefore,
$$
\operatorname{Var}(\hat{\beta})=\sigma^2\mathsf{E}\left[\sum x_i^2\right]^{-1}.
$$