# Finite sample variance of OLS estimator for random regressor

Tags: statistics, regression, variance, estimation, linear-regression

I am trying to derive the finite sample variance of an OLS estimator when the regressor is also random. More concretely, I am looking at the following case:

$$
Y_i = \beta X_i + \epsilon_i
$$
where
$$
X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2_x) \\
\epsilon_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2_\epsilon)
$$

and $X_i$ and $\epsilon_i$ are independent. I know that the OLS estimator $\widehat{\beta}$ is:

$$
\widehat{\beta} = \frac{\sum X_i Y_i}{\sum X^2_i}
$$

The $X_i$ and $\epsilon_i$ are i.i.d.

I want to compute the finite sample variance of $\widehat{\beta}$. I have only come across variance results which assume that the regressor $X$ is fixed, i.e., for $\text{Var}(\widehat{\beta}|X)$.

Note, I was able to derive the asymptotic variance of $\widehat{\beta}$. I am stuck on the finite sample case.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3417663/321264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
Var(\hat{\beta}) &= E(Var(\hat{\beta}|X)) + Var(E(\hat{\beta}|X))\\
&= E\left( \frac{\sigma^2_{\epsilon}}{\sum X_i^2} \right) + Var(\beta)\\
\end{align}
As $X_i$ are i.i.d normal random variables with zero mean and variance of $\sigma^2_{x}$, thus $\sum X_i^2/\sigma_x^2$ is distributed $\chi^2(n)$  hence $(\sum X_i^2/\sigma_x^2)^{-1}$ is distributed Inverse chi squared with with mean of $1/(n-2)$, thus 
\begin{align}
Var(\hat{\beta}) &= E\left( \frac{\sigma^2_{\epsilon}}{\sigma_x^2} \text{Inv-}\chi^2(n) =  \right)=\frac{\sigma^2_{\epsilon}}{(n-2)\sigma_x^2} 
\end{align}

Comment: @StubbornAtom The conditional variance of $Z$ in your answer is problematic as it should not contain $\sigma_x^2$.

Comment: @Shantanu It is better to open a new thread for the other question so it can be clearly formulated